# Correct way to secure SER cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am running 250-250-250-3/0 SER from an outside disconnect to an indoor breaker panel and want to make sure I am properly securing the cable where it enters each box. The problem that I am running into is that the common sizes of clamps (like the one in the link below) are too small. What is my best option?

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-2-in-Clamp-on-Type-Service-Entrance-Connector-Conduit-Fitting/1087593

Comment: Any reason you can't do conduit? NM clamps are basically only available up to 2 inch, but conduit is easy to source in 3 inch, which will easy hold cable that size.

Comment: You're limited by your suppliers.  Letting the TV set tell you where to exclusively shop, in electrical, is like tying one hand behind your back.  Get to know a friendly neighborhood electrical supply.

Answer (score 1):

### That's because that clamp is designed for flat-ish cables

Your problem is that you're looking at a clamp designed for flat-ish (SEU) cables.  For the SER cable you're using, you need something designed for round cables instead -- you should have no trouble getting your cable to fit into an Arlington 849S fitting, for instance.